# Kickstarter project on an OPT-STEM in the US

Tags: united-states, visa

I'm currently working as a Software Developer on an F-1 visa with my OPT for a company in the US. While I'm working here I want to start a kickstarter campaign to fund my personal project. I should say that I'm not planning to quit my job until I get a Greencard, so I will still be fulfilling my requirements for the OPT-STEM. I have asked Kickstarter if there would be any problems with them about starting a project, they said I'm eligible by their standards to start a project. But my real concern is, am I legally allowed to start a campaign in my name with an OPT-STEM EAD card. I couldn't find a lawyer that has a decisive answer to this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: legal advice is explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]

Comment: Lawrence, how do you know that I don't already have a product but simply I need more resources to continue the project?

Comment: The correct way for doing this is to create a business plan and pitch it to investors. If they like it, there's your kickstarter. If they don't, you go back to the whiteboard and try again until they do.

Comment: I have my reasons for choosing kickstarter instead of going to the investors first, and this is not a debate platform. The question is marked answered so I will have to stop this argument.

Comment: If a real lawyer is unable to give you an answer, then there is absolutely no way a bunch of people on the internet is going to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a legal question. The best (and only sensible) option is to contact a lawyer who specializes in immigration. Many will answer a question like this free of charge.

If there are different opinions, then that means the law isn't clear - which in my experience isn't unusual for immigration cases. In those circumstances I'd tend to adopt a more conservative approach if keeping your F-1 visa is important to you.